# Is there a way we can embed tex code and visualize the rendered compiled output in tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: tex-core

This website is very useful. In many situations, when answering or asking questions, it is very helpful to embed executable code and visualize the rendered compiled output to demonstrate what the contributor means. I was unable to find information regarding this functionally.

Is there a way we can embed `tex` code and visualize and visualize the rendered compiled output in `tex.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: This question comes up regularly. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/35864 and many linked discussions on Meta. The gist is that rendering of TeX-like input on the StackExchange network is not actually done by TeX (but by MathJax and friends). We want to discuss the actual code and if we need to showcase the output, a screenshot works fine for most.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on meta not here, but if transfered would be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Welcome. // Make screenshots and post in your question.

Comment: @moewe Although, according to you, the question comes regularly, searching for *this exact information* (for example [asking google](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=Is+there+a+way+we+can+embed+tex+code+and+visualize+the+rendered+compiled+output+in+tex.stackexchange.com%3F)) delivered no usable results. A excellent concise answer to this question would be "No, at the moment there is no way".

Comment: I just clicked on your Google link and the 14th and 15th finds were the most relevant questions on the meta site. By putting the url in the question you weighted the search results very heavily to this site, where you find questions about _other_ sites since questions about _this_ site are almost always off-topic here.

Comment: If you prefer an online platform for compiling .tex-files to a local .tex-installation, the [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) project might be of interest to you. There is the possibility of creating a free account. You can choose between different releases of the TeX Live distribution. However the compiler is run in batchmode or nonstopmode, thus you cannot interact via console. Also you need to get used to how to get the .log-file of the tex/latex-run displayed.

Comment: People might abuse the possibility of compiling/rendering .tex-input on this site for document preparation. Which in turn might slow down the site.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after comments by moewe, David Carlisle and MS-SPO:

**No, at the moment there is no way**.

The way people overcome this limitation is by a) inserting the code with Markdown, b) then externally compiling that code, c) making an image of the rendered result and (if you are lucky to have the right amount of "reputation"), d) insert that image in the post.

A great insight is provided by Ulrich Diez (I quote):

If you don't have the reputation needed for posting images here, you can upload the image somewhere else, post your contribution here, providing the url leading to your screenshot.If you have the url, you can use markdown syntax directly for "inserting" the image: In the text do s.th. like `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` and at the bottom do s.th. like `[1]: https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.jpg`

Comment: note this is not a technical limitation, other sites in the network eg https://math.stackexchange.com/ have mathjax enabled. It is disabled here by request.

Comment: Technical aspect: If you don't have the reputation needed for posting images here, you can upload the image somewhere else, post your contribution here, providing the url leading to your screenshot.If you have the url, you can use markdown syntax directly for "inserting" the image: In the text do s.th. like `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` and at the bottom do s.th. like `[1]: https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.jpg`. The URL must be `https://...`. Legal aspect: **Ensuring that uploading/publishing the image is okay regarding copy-rights etc is up to you.**